# Why can't the C# compiler deduce type parameters for return values?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have this code (minimized for clarity):

```
interface IEither<out TL, out TR> {
}

class Left<TL, TR> : IEither<TL, TR> {
    public Left(TL value) { }
}

static class Either {
    public static IEither<TL, TR> Left<TL, TR> (this TL left) {
        return new Left<TL, TR> (left);
    }
}
```

Why can't I say:

```
static class Foo
{
    public static IEither<string, int> Bar ()
    {
        //return "Hello".Left (); // Doesn't compile
        return "Hello".Left<string, int> (); // Compiles
    }
}
```

I get an error stating that `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Left' and no extension method 'Left' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)`.

Comment: This is a very good question - especially considering that you can return lambdas the same way and type inference will work fine. But I'm afraid we can only guess.

Comment: Not sure what is `Foo` and `Bar`. Can you post a complete reproducible sample ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel added MWE

Comment: @Alex then why the line above it compiles?

Comment: The type arguments should be inferrable from the function call itself, not from the body of the function, so in your case, how do you think that type `int` should be derived from just the type `string`?

Comment: (Once properly copy-pasted, it builds, disregard the sily me) You listed out the parameters, so it compiles

Comment: @Mathew because there are no other options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to have a look at section **7.5.2** in the `C#` specification.

> **7.5.2 Type inference**
>
> When a generic method is called without specifying type arguments, a
>    *type inference* process attempts to infer type arguments for the call.
>    The presence of type inference allows a more convenient syntax to be
>    used for calling a generic method, and allows the programmer to avoid
>    specifying redundant type information.
>
> [...]
>
> Type inference occurs as part of the binding-time processing of a method invocation (§7.6.5.1) and takes place before the overload resolution step of the invocation [...]

Ie the resolution takes place before any kind of overload resolution is done, the problem is that inferring the types the way you said is not even tried, and is frankly not always possible either.

Type resolution for the arguments for generic types is only done with the arguments in the invocation! In you example only a `string`! It cannot infer `int` from the arguments, only the invocation context which isn't resolved at the time of the generic type-resolution.

Comment: So it's simply a matter of "we're not doing it in a way that allows that kind of inference"?

Comment: Exactly. I would say it's not intentional, just a side-effect of how type resolution is implemented with regards to overload resolution.

Answer (score 6):

```
return "Hello".Left<string, int> (); // Compiles
```

No surprise. You stated the type parameters explicitly and the compiler is happy.

```
return "Hello".Left (); // Doesn't compile
```

No surprise either, compiler has no way to find out what is `TR` in this case. `TL` can be inferred because `TL` is passed as a parameter `left` but `TR` cannot.

C# compiler makes no assumptions in what you meant, If the intent is not clear it will throw a compiler error. If compiler thinks you might be doing something wrong it gives a compiler warning.

Comment: My point is that the only possible value for `TR` is int, and I would like to know why the compiler can't figure it out on its own

Comment: The only possible value of `TR` *for the return value to be acceptable* is `int`. `TR` itself doesn't have this constraint.

Comment: @miniBill How on earth compiler will infer it? Inference is not based on return value. You could simply write `"Hello".Left();` without assigning the result or returning it. In this case what should the compiler do? What the compiler has to infer for `TR`?

Comment: `return tree => tree.DoSomethingWith(arg)` *does* work as the only statement in a method and the compiler is very happy to infer what you mean about the type of `tree`, despite the fact that you're not assigning to a local. It actually does go to the declaration of the method, checks the return type (even if it's a generic delegate) and uses it to perform type inference. So what the OP is asking is far from being unheard of.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Give me a complete example to speculate. I have no idea what is `tree`, what is `DoSomethingWith`, what is `arg`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `DoSomethingWith(string)` is a method that simply returns `true`, `arg` is a `string`, the whole method that returns the lambda is `Predicate<Tree>`, where `Tree` is a type that only has the `DoSomethingWith(string)` method.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis That is method group type inference which definitely checks for what is the type of local variable you're assigning to, if you're returning it, it will use the return type etc. But OP's example if generic method call. It doesn't involves these steps. Because lambda itself doesn't have a type. It can be converted to a compatible delegate type, so it refers to return value or local variable type etc. For instance if you say var v = `tree => tree.DoSomethingWith(arg);`  that won't compile because we don't know what is `tree`, `arg` etc

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes. But OP isn't doing `var v = "Hello".Left ();` either. He's doing `return "Hello".Left()` in a method with a very specific (and matchable) return type: `IEither<string, int>`.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis That's what. You're not creating a delegate here. Those rules are only applicable when creating a `delegate` or `Expression<TDelegate>`. When calling a method they are irrelevant. Am sorry I can't find the specification about this, you can check it out and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No, I'm not saying you're wrong. In fact, you're absolutely correct - these apply only to delegates. I'm just saying that since they apply to *something* in the language, then the (hypothetical) feature OP wishes for isn't really impossible and it's not a matter of the compiler making assumptions either. There *is* a mechanism in the compiler for traversing the AST backwards (or something to that effect) and performing more complicated type inference (not assumptions). It's just that they decided to keep it only for one specific circumstance and I felt it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer involves guessing.

The information about `TR` lies in the fact that it's used as the child expression of `return` which, in turn, could be matched with `IEither<Foo, Bar>`, to produce the information that `TR` is `Bar`.

But there's a problem. When the compiler has an abstract syntax tree, it is easier to start from the root and infer expression types, resolve overloads, etc by progressively moving towards the leaves of the tree. This is the easiest thing to do and the thing that gets done more often.

Your scenario requires the compiler to work completely backwards - from the method call to the constructor call to the child expression of `return` and then to consult the declaration of the current method (and find out that the correct combination is `<string, int>`, because any other can't possibly compile). At first glance, this is hard to achieve.

But there is some precedence for this in C#: you can create a (higher order) function that simply returns a lambda and type inference *will* work based on the declaration. This kind of thing also works with lambdas when declaring a local variable (you can't assign them to `var` and ask the compiler to infer the parameter types from later usage in the scope).

So, why didn't they implement it for the case you're describing, considering they did it with lambdas?

1. They *had* to do it with lambdas: the whole point of lambda expressions is that they shouldn't look like a big deal - they should be as easy to write as possible (in order to quickly express a filtering criterion, a sorting criterion, etc). This has value.
2. Even though this kind of thing works with lambdas, it's far from perfect - in fact, it can behave in very weird ways from time to time. So it may be seen by the designers as a necessary evil that shouldn't be extended to the rest of the language.
3. Your case is rarer and the workaround is easy.
4. It may simply be a case of "nobody has implemented it *yet*".